# When I am running in intellIj the same code is working properly but when running in eclipse with STS support I am gettinh below error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repo.StudentRepo' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.example.demo.AddData.main(AddData.java:16)
```

Comment: This is because Spring cannot locate the 'com.example.repo.StudentRepo' class.  I'm not sure why running it in one ide works and the other no. Regardless, you can specify it so it works in all environments.  It looks like SpringBoot.  Try using `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.*"})`

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with Spring Boot application you can always run it using maven or gradle for example : `./gradlew bootRun` or `./mvnw spring-boot:run`.
If it runs when you use those tools then everything is fine with your application and you probably make some mistake when you import it to your IDE.
It's hard to say what exacly wrong is with your config but try to check [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4) post and see if you can find any differences to your configuration.